# Jmeter stop running whenever window is auto logout or sleep mode in remote

Tags: jmeter

is there a tool or plugin to make Jmeter to run whenever window is auto logout or sleep mode in remote.

Answer (score 0):

1. Logout == [end of session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/multipoint-services/end-a-user-session) including all running apps.
2. Sleep == machine is turned off, the state of current applications is [suspended to RAM](https://www.howtogeek.com/783969/what-does-sleep-mean-in-windows/)

In case if "Logout" == just locking the screen or terminating the remote session due to inactivity - then JMeter should be running. If there are custom scripts which additionally closes all open application windows - you can work it around by installing JMeter slave process (I'm talking about [distributed mode of JMeter execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)) as a [Windows service](https://dzone.com/articles/installing-a-java-application-as-a-windows-service) so it will be started automatically when computer starts and theoretically it should persist logoffs.